# Deploying Docker Image from Azure Container Registry to Web App Container "failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1)"

Tags: linux, azure, containers

I've tried latest Ubuntu and Python - they successfully extract and mount. However, as soon as I install further dependencies and add my app and push the image to Azure ACR - this error happens.

What is happening on my local machine? I have the Ubuntu image running for example, I install pip3 for example, and "docker commit" the changes locally, then tag the image and push it to ACR. This image will then fail to load with the above error.  I can see that the segments in the previous image are already in the registry and only the latest image segment is actually pushed. So the error appears to occur with the latest change to the image.

The full error message is:-

> 2020-06-25T03:14:43.517Z ERROR - failed to register layer: Error
> processing tar file(exit status 1): Container ID 197609 cannot be
> mapped to a host IDErr: 0, Message: failed to register layer: Error
> processing tar file(exit status 1): Container ID 197609 cannot be
> mapped to a host ID
>
> 2020-06-25T03:14:43.589Z INFO  - Pull Image
> failed, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 46 Seconds
>
> 2020-06-25T03:14:43.590Z ERROR - Pulling docker image *******.azurecr.io/seistech-1:v1.0.0.15
> failed:
>
> 2020-06-25T03:14:43.590Z INFO  - Pulling image from Docker
> hub: *******.azurecr.io/seistech-1:v1.0.0.15 2020-06-25T03:14:43.987Z
> ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status
> code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get
> https://*******.azurecr.io/v2/*******-1/manifests/v1.0.0.15:
> unauthorized: authentication required, visit
> https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}
>
> 2020-06-25T03:14:44.020Z ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker
> image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
>
> 2020-06-25T03:14:46.491Z INFO  - Stopping site *******-dev-container
> because it failed during startup.

Note re' authentication message(s) - I have created system assigned identity in the web app and assigned image pull permissions in the ACR - so as far as I can tell, there should be no auth issue.

Suggestions appreciated - very little diagnostic info to work with.

Thanks
Andy, NZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I took several days to find this [documentation page](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/high-uid-error/)

The key piece of info in the container error log is this:

```
...container id xxxxxx cannot be mapped...
```

And the shell script to find these items is this:

```
$ find / \( -uid 1000000 \)  -ls 2>/dev/null
```

(where `1000000` is the high ID from the error message)

The solution then was simple, in the final step of my docker-compose Dockerfile I added:

```
&& chown -R root:root /home
```

which is where the find command show all the problematic files were - they were created by a `tar -x` operation. I haven't dug further into whether this caused the permissions problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was related to `npm v9` and only when using ***Azure App Service***.

may install modules into your node_modules directory with a high ID for the file owner/creator.

### My Solution:

As a quick workaround, I reverted back to an older version of npm `8.x`. That worked for me at the moment.

Found this article to be helpful
[NPM-specific issues causing users remapping exceptions](https://azureossd.github.io/2022/06/30/Docker-User-Namespace-remapping-issues/#npm-specific-issues-causing-userns-remap-exceptions)

Comment: This was the issue for me. Downgraded my `Dockerfile` to use npm8 and my Azure App Service started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

The Managed identity cannot be authentication to deploy the Docker image from the ACR. You must set the environment such as:

- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME - The username for the ACR server.
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL - The full URL to the ACR server. (For example, https://my-server.azurecr.io.)
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD - The password for the ACR server.

This is the only way to pull the image from a private registry and so for ACR. The managed identity just works when the Web App running, but pulling the image is before it.

Comment: Thanks Charles, I see that these attributes are correctly configured in the web app configuration.

Comment: @badcop666 Do you check if the credential is really right?

Comment: Thanks Charles, yes when I manually create the app service (I'm using an ARM template otherwise) configuring the container settings populates the app settings you mentioned - within the same subscription this works as expected. The system-assigned AAD identity I added isn't necessary.
Regards.

Comment: @badcop666 I'm glad it's helpful. And if it works, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable admin credentials in the azure container registry so that the app service will get authorization to pull the image from the container.

You can also create a managed identity with ACRpull role to pull the image if using managed identity.

[Enable admin user to use admin credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj2AS.png)